# Возврат на главную страницу

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

На главной странице расположена форма заказа, она посылает данные на файл mail.php ( этот файл проверяет и отсылает данные на почту) и показывается страница mail.php (пустая страница). 
Вопрос: Как сделать так что бы после отсылки данных отображалась главная страница? Или как сделать отправку фоновой?

Comment: ajax, асинхронная передача данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({url:"mail.php", type:"POST", data:{get_form_values()});
```

get_form_values() - функция должна возвращать данные формы, можно реализовать например так:

```
function get_form_values(form_name)
{
    result = new Array();
    $('#'+form_name+' :input').each(
    function(i,elem)
    {
        //alert($(this).attr("type"));
        if( ($(this).attr("type")!='radio') 
            ||($(this).attr("type")=='radio'&& $(this).attr("checked") !== undefined ) )
            result.push({$(this).attr("name"):$(this).val()});
    }
    );
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавить в конце кода PHP следующую строчку

```
header('Location: http://www.scriptsite.ru');
```

где вместо http://www.scriptsite.ru указываете адрес главной страницы. Главное что до этой строки не должно быть ни одного вывода (echo, print() и пр.)

P.S. Если требуется вывод то можно сделать так:

```
echo '<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.scriptsite.ru" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Вы будете перемещены на главную страницу в течении 5 секунд.
    </body>
</html>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Но скорее всего в Вашем случае не сработает, так как если есть какой-либо вывод в браузер (echo или print), то эта команда не сработает, можете попробовать! Если не заработает то только AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на JavaScript (нужно добавить в конец):

```
<script>
    document.location.href='index.php';
</script>
```

index.php - Адрес главной страницы